# AWS Code Build (Windows Image) Tcp ports are blocked

Tags: amazon-web-services, octopus-deploy, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild, octopus

I have set up my .net core 2.1 projects on the AWS Code Build window Image. In my build spec yaml file, I am pushing my built package to the octopus server which uses specific TCP port but it seems like the port is blocked and I am unable to make the connection to the Octopus server.

Comment: Do you have the Octopus server hosted in the same VPC account? or are you using there cloud version

Answer (score 0):

Use a VPC configuration with CodeBuild. You can specify the Security Group yourself that is attached to the ENI CodeBuild provisions in your VPC and used by your build container. One caveat though, with VPC Configuration on a build project, you must use NAT Gateway if reaching your Octopus server over the internet.